# Azure Cloud Static website - map custom root domain to cdn with https

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I'm trying to host a static website in Azure. Since I want to refer 3 different domain-names to the website, I created a CDN for it. The SSL certificate could be successfully created for the subdomain www. (www.mydomain.com)

No SSL certificate can be created for the root domain (mydomain.com). Following error message appears:

> Enabling Https with CDN Managed Certificate is not supported anymore for apex (root) domains

My domain registrar only contains the NS entries for the DNS zone of mydomain.com (for example ns1-10.azure-dns.com). 

I manage the DNS entries via the Azure-Cloud "DNS zone" function.  My CNAME entries are:

`*         CNAME 300 mydomain.azureedge.net`
`cdnverify CNAME 300 cdnyverify.mydomain.azureedge.net`

I have defined the following two custom domains for the CDN:
`www.mydomain.com (SSL approved)`
`mydomain.com (Not possible to SSL approve - see error above)`

It works now to access the page via HTTP and HTTPS for www.mydomain.com

How can I access the static website via root domain via HTTP and HTTPS ? So https://mydomain.ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had to realize that *DNZ Zone from Azure is not the best choice in this case*. Neither the DNS management of Azure nor that of my registrar allows CNAME on root domains. 
I have now moved the DNS handling to **cloudflare**. There you can create a CNAME for the root domain with "@". It works now. The SSL issue for the root domain seems not to matter. SSL works for some reason for the Root-Domain, too.

Comment: doesnt seem to work when i manually type in https://{domain}.com

Answer (score 1):

Alias Recordset that Point an Azure resource are supported. CNAME on an Apex is not in the DNS standard.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-alias#point-zone-apex-to-azure-cdn-endpoints

Comment: Would be nice to quote an extract from the website in your answer. Links get eventually broken